# How to avoid RuntimeError while call __dict__ on module?

Tags: dictionary, runtime-error, magic-methods, python-3.10

it is appearing in some big modules like matplotlib. For example expression :

```
import importlib
obj = importlib.import_module('matplotlib')
obj_entries = obj.__dict__
```

Between runs len of **obj_entries** can vary. From 108 to 157 (expected) entries. Especially pyplot can be ignored like some another submodules.
it can work stable during manual debug mode with len computing statement after **dict** extraction. But in auto it dont work well.

such error occures:

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
python-BaseException
```

using clear python 3.10 on windows. Version swap change nothing at all

Answer (score 0):

during some attempts some interesting features was found.
use of ****repr**** is helpfull before **dict** initiation.
But if module transported between classes like variable more likely lazy-import happening? For now there is evidence that not all names showing when command line interpriter doing opposite - returning what expected. So this junk of code help bypass this bechavior...
Note: using **pkgutil.iter_modules(some_path)** to observe modules im internal for **pkgutil ModuleInfo** form.

```
import pkgutil, importlib

module_info : pkgutil.ModuleInfo
name = module_info.name
founder = module_info.module_finder
spec = founder.find_spec(name)
module_obj = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
loader = module_obj.__loader__
loader.exec_module(module_obj)
```

still unfamilliar with interior of import mechanics so it will be helpfull to recive some links to more detail explanation (spot on)